# No response: Matlab and Modbus TCP

Tags: matlab, modbus

Hi there i have this code to read data from Modbus register 40001:

```
function [s] = serialstart(opt)
% Funtion for initializing a serial interface in matlab for interfacing

% Functions using the serial port must be passed the serial port object
% s in order for the serial port to be acessable.  

port = 502;  
%   link = tcpip('127.0.0.1',502);  
%   link = tcpip('10.64.15.101',502);  
s = tcpip('192.168.2.177',port);  
%?????  
set(s, 'InputBufferSize', 30000); 

% Initialize serial port on specified com port
date_addr   = 40001;
date_num=1;
date_addr_high = floor(date_addr/100);  
date_addr_low = mod(date_addr,100);  
date_num_high = floor(date_num/100);  
date_num_low = mod(date_num,100); 
%Open serial connection



fopen(s);

% Specify Terminator
s.terminator='CR/LF';




fwrite(s,0,'char')                      %Transactio identifier        0x00  
fwrite(s,0,'char')                      %  Transactio identifier                   0x00  
fwrite(s,0,'char')                      %    Protokol identifier      0x00  
fwrite(s,0,'char')                      %        Protokol identifier              0x00  
fwrite(s,0,'char')                      %     Anzahl Datenbytes  0x00  
fwrite(s,1,'char')                      %         Anzahl Datenbytes        0x06  
fwrite(s,255,'char')                     %     unit identifier    0xff  
fwrite(s,3,'uint8')                       %  Funktion           0x03  
fwrite(s,date_addr_high,'uint8')         %Startadresse High Byte   
fwrite(s,date_addr_low,'uint8')            %Startadresse Low Byte
fwrite(s,0,'uint8')           %Anzahl Register Low Byte
fwrite(s,2,'uint8')     %Anzahl Register High Byte


while ~s.BytesAvailable
end
s.BytesAvailable
res=fread(s,s.BytesAvailable)                 
fclose(s);
```

I get no response. Matlab doesn't get back to the command prompt. The Modbus slave is a arduino with an ethernet shield. When i test with a modbus master (e.g. Modbus Poll), i can read Register 40001.

Comment: You are not reading 40001, the code reads 156065

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modbus TCP and MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416239/modbus-tcp-and-matlab)

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I changed the code.

Comment: I posted a [lengthy answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36720546/5171120) at the duplicate question. For this question, I'll say that Matlab doesn't get back to the prompt if you're stuck in a while loop - you aren't receiving any bytes back. I'd guess it's because the message wasn't formatted correctly and the slave is either waiting for more data to be sent (If 'Anzahl Datenbytes' is bigger than it should be) or it didn't know it should respond at all (if you totally botched the message).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that your sixth byte:

```
fwrite(s,1,'char')       %Anzahl Datenbytes 0x06
```

is a 1, not 0x06?  This byte in the protocol is the payload data size, and if you have it set to '1', I doubt any good Modbus Slave will respond.

The second thing to check is it looks like you are writing to a Modbus Slave address of 255.  In my experience, this isn't usually used as a valid ID (although it works with the protocol).  Make sure the slave you are trying to communicate with will respond to a unit ID 255.

Good luck!

Comment: I changed it fwrite(s,6,'char'). My Device responds on the ID. I have tested this.